# Значение None при парсинге с помощью BS4

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup, web-scraping

Учусь пользоваться Bs4 и возникла следующая ошибка, почему то не находит ссылку на страницу. Подскажите плиз, что делать.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_first_news():
    headers = {
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36"
    }

    url = 'https://kaliningrad.rbc.ru/kaliningrad'
    r = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    article_cards = soup.find_all('div', class_='item__wrap l-col-center')

    for article in article_cards:
        article_title = article.find('span', class_='item__title rm-cm-item-text').text.strip()
        article_url = article.get('href')

        print (f'{article_title} | {article_url}')

get_first_news()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ссылка находится в объекте `<a>`, а вы пытаетесь достать ссылку из родительского объекта.

Решение:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_first_news():
    headers = {
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36"
    }

    url = 'https://kaliningrad.rbc.ru/kaliningrad'
    r = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    article_cards = soup.find_all('div', class_='item__wrap l-col-center')

    for article in article_cards:
        article_title = article.find('span', class_='item__title rm-cm-item-text').text.strip()
        article_url = article.find('a').get('href')

        print (f'{article_title} | {article_url}')

get_first_news()
```